# Find a word in a file and then to put in array the next 10 values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a text file, and I want to put 10 values in array from the first time that I see specific word. Lets suppose that the text contains:

```
...,sometext,moretext,wordddddd,867767,3468647,sometext,...
```

and I want to put in array the first 10 values after the word `wordddddd`,
i.e `array[0]` will be `867767` and `array[1]` will be `34686` and so on. I don't need the commas in the array, the language is PHP.

in my attempt I tried to scan the whole file, and if I see the word `wordddddd` then to do a `for` loop that will iterate 10 times to fill in the first 10 places in the array. I used `explode` to split the words from the comma.

I marked the line with the error
How can I do that? Some PHP expert please? Here is my attempt:

```
   <?php
    $id='wordddddd';
    $handle = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
    $valid = false; // init as false
    $arr=explode(",", $handle);// ERROR IN THIS LINE Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in 
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($buffer, $id) !== false) {
            $valid = TRUE;
            $pos=strpos($buffer, $id);
            echo 'Its there in pos ',$pos;
            for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++){
                echo $valid[$x+$pos+1];

            }

            break; // Once you find the string, you should break out the loop.
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
    ?>
```

Comment: In the error line try to swap the parameters : explode($handle, ",")

Comment: @ItzikChaimov stiil does'n't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id='wordddddd';
$fopen = fopen("file.txt", 'r');
$content= htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("file.txt"));//
$split=explode(",", $content);
$arr_len=count($split);
$pos=0;
$result=array();

//finding the position of the word in the array
foreach ($split as $x){
    if(stripos($id, $x)!==false) {
    break;}
    $pos++;
}

for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
    $result[$x]=$split[$pos+1];
    $pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $your_word = 'wordddddd';
$number_of_items_to_limit = 10;
$array = explode(",", file_get_contents('text.txt')); //Explode file content by ","
$found = false; //Set dafault value for key word flag to false
$array = array_filter( // remove all items without found flag
    $array,
    function($value) use (&$found,&$your_word) {
        if($value == $your_word) {
            $found = true; // set flag to found
        }
        if($found) {
            return true ; //return items that are coming after the flag
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
$result = array_slice($array, 0, $number_of_items_to_limit); // return only first 10 items from array
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). It will save you the call to `explode`.
Here is the example from the man page:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the $handle variable to read the file line by line and sotre it an array.
Then you need to match the $id value.
The error is because the explode() will not  work for the $handle but for a string variable which is not case.